# Configuring Motion to run as daemon in Raspberry and right (?) issues

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, motion, start-stop-daemon

I'm able to tun my motion detection in my Raspberry 2:

In */etc/default/motion*

I changed *start_motion_daemon=no* to *start_motion_daemon=yes*

Next I enabled motion by entering the following at the command line:

```
sudo systemctl enable motion
```

Finally

```
reboot or sudo service motion restart
```

And my status with

```
sudo service motion status
```

is

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service motion status
● motion.service - LSB: Start Motion detection
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/motion)
   Active: active (running) since So 2016-10-30 17:49:26 CET; 4min 25s ago
  Process: 1076 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/motion stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1109 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/motion start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/motion.service
           └─1120 /usr/bin/motion

Okt 30 17:52:52 raspberrypi motion[1120]: [1] [NTC] [EVT] event_newfile: File of type 1 saved to: /home/pi/motion/01-20161030175252-00.jpg
Okt 30 17:52:53 raspberrypi motion[1120]: [1] [NTC] [EVT] event_newfile: File of type 1 saved to: /home/pi/motion/01-20161030175252-01.jpg
Okt 30 17:53:01 raspberrypi motion[1120]: [1] [NTC] [EVT] event_newfile: File of type 1 saved to: /home/pi/motion/01-20161030175300-01.jpg
```

but my triggered motion (test)event in */etc/motion/motion.conf*

```
on_event_start echo "event start"%f >> /home/pi/motion.detect
```

only works when I do

```
sudo motion
```

and not with

```
sudo service motion restart
sudo /etc/init.d/motion restart
```

**First main question**: Has someone a clue, what's wrong here ?

**Second question**: Why gives sudo /etc/init.d/motion restart an output 
in command line

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/motion restart
[ ok ] Restarting motion (via systemctl): motion.service.
```

and

```
sudo service motion restart
```

not ?

Comment: Is `/home/pi/motion` writable for user `motion`?

Comment: Thank you, it was a sign in the right direction ! After sudo motion:motion /home/pi/motion -R it works